# Javascript for Automation not launching correct application

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to write an automation Javascript to test my app's AppleScript functionality. I want it to launch my dev build, so I started off like so:

```
my_app = Application('/Users/Dov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efmlzhsvapzuwcfqxjxhhuncpogy/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app')
```

When I run the script, it launches another build in a totally different directory. However, the following AppleScript *does* launch the intended dev build:

```
tell application "/Users/Dov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-efmlzhsvapzuwcfqxjxhhuncpogy/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app"
    activate
end tell
```

Shouldn't these both behave the same way? And how/why would it look for another app with the same Bundle ID? [This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW6) says my Javascript syntax should work:

> **Accessing Applications**
>
> Applications can be accessed in these ways:
>
> 1. Name
>
>    `Application('Mail')`
> 2. Bundle ID
>
>    `Application('com.apple.mail')`
> 3. Path
>
>    `Application('/Applications/Mail.app')`
>
> `...`

Comment: You should always use AppleScript to test your application's scripting interface. A lot of Apple event functionality just doesn't work right, fails, or is completely missing in JXA and Scripting Bridge. AppleScript may suck as a language, but it's the de facto standard and the only supported option that actually speaks Apple events correctly.

Comment: Hmm. What if you make a new String object and set it to the path, **then** set my_app to that string? Just spit-balling here.